# Looking for a 1970's sci-fi audiobook for kids

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, audio-book

I remember getting a sci-fi audiobook from my local library a number of times. It was on cassette but I'm assuming it had a print version too.

I remember a child from the planet Utopia(?) visiting Earth on some sort of exchange and being amazed that water was actually falling from the sky and the other kid telling him it was only rain.

This would have been in the mid 1970s.

Comment: Can you recall any other details about this book?